# Jquery mobile autocomplete and Geonames

Tags: json, jquery-mobile, autocomplete, geonames

I'm trying to use an automplete field to find locations, and I see the example for Jquery Mobile shown here based on Geobytes database:
http://view.jquerymobile.com/1.3.1/dist/demos/widgets/autocomplete/autocomplete-remote.html

```
$( document ).on( "pageinit", "#myPage", function() {
$( "#autocomplete" ).on( "listviewbeforefilter", function ( e, data ) {
    var $ul = $( this ),
        $input = $( data.input ),
        value = $input.val(),
        html = "";
    $ul.html( "" );
    if ( value && value.length > 2 ) {
        $ul.html( "<li><div class='ui-loader'><span class='ui-icon ui-icon-loading'></span></div></li>" );
        $ul.listview( "refresh" );
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://gd.geobytes.com/AutoCompleteCity",
            dataType: "jsonp",
            crossDomain: true,
            data: {
                q: $input.val()
            }
        })
        .then( function ( response ) {
            $.each( response, function ( i, val ) {
                html += "<li>" + val + "</li>";
            });
            $ul.html( html );
            $ul.listview( "refresh" );
            $ul.trigger( "updatelayout");
        });
    }
});
});
```

But I would to use the Geonames service, beacause it contain a most large DB. Here is an example with JqueryUI autocomplete:
http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote-jsonp

```
  $(function() {
function log( message ) {
  $( "<div>" ).text( message ).prependTo( "#log" );
  $( "#log" ).scrollTop( 0 );
}

$( "#city" ).autocomplete({
  source: function( request, response ) {
    $.ajax({
      url: "http://ws.geonames.org/searchJSON",
      dataType: "jsonp",
      data: {
        featureClass: "P",
        style: "full",
        maxRows: 12,
        name_startsWith: request.term
      },
      success: function( data ) {
        response( $.map( data.geonames, function( item ) {
          return {
            label: item.name + (item.adminName1 ? ", " + item.adminName1 : "") + ", " + item.countryName,
            value: item.name
          }
        }));
      }
    });
  },
  minLength: 2,
  select: function( event, ui ) {
    log( ui.item ?
      "Selected: " + ui.item.label :
      "Nothing selected, input was " + this.value);
  },
  open: function() {
    $( this ).removeClass( "ui-corner-all" ).addClass( "ui-corner-top" );
  },
  close: function() {
    $( this ).removeClass( "ui-corner-top" ).addClass( "ui-corner-all" );
  }
});
});
```

I'm trying to combine the 2 examples but without success... :( Can I have an help? 
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved! :) This is the full working code:

```
        $( document ).on( "pageinit", "#myPage", function() {
        $( "#autocomplete" ).on( "listviewbeforefilter", function ( e, data ) {
            var $ul = $( this ),
                $input = $( data.input ),
                value = $input.val(),
                html = "";
            $ul.html( "" );
            if ( value && value.length > 2 ) {
                $ul.html( "<li><div class='ui-loader'><span class='ui-icon ui-icon-loading'></span></div></li>" );
                $ul.listview( "refresh" );
                $.ajax({
                    url: "http://ws.geonames.org/searchJSON",
                    dataType: "jsonp",
                    crossDomain: true,
                    data: {
                        featureClass: "P",
                        style: "full",
                        maxRows: 12,
                        lang: "it",
                        name_startsWith: $input.val()
                    }
                })
                .then( function ( response ) {
                    $.each( response.geonames, function ( i, val ) {
                        html += "<li>" + val.name + (val.adminName1 ? ", " + val.adminName1 : "") + ", " + val.countryName + "</li>";
                    });
                    $ul.html( html );
                    $ul.listview( "refresh" );
                    $ul.trigger( "updatelayout");
                });
            }
        });
    });
```

Hope it can helps! ;)